# collapse and expand button in a google site

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I'm working on a Google site as I though it was easier...But I'm having some troubles with it. I'd like to create a button that expand and collapsea block of text. I've tried some different options but I didn't get it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle between hiding and showing the paragraphs</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you can use JavaScript, you can set the style to `"display:none;"` or `"display:block;"` by clicking a button.

```
<div id="ThisTextWillBeHidden">This text needs to be hidden</div>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById("ThisTextWillBeHidden").style.display='none';">
    Click me to hide!
</button>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById("ThisTextWillBeHidden").style.display='block';">
    Click me to show!
</button>
```

I assume Google Sites does not support scripts, so you will need to save this code somewhere else, like on your hosting or in a file storage service, and call it like this:

```
<iframe src="location of the file containing your code.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: I can not make it work.....It's so strange.

Comment: I've created a notepad with the code and saved it in the Desktop. After that I've got the location of the file(C:\....) and then I've created an HTML box with the last part of the code, but it doesn't work. Am I doing it right?